# VBA: Find and replace text

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

In my word document, there are multiple instances of ABC, but only one of ABC123.

My task is to find the one instance of ABC123 and copy it onto a separate word document. As there are thousands of documents I will need to sort through, I would like to make a macro to relieve some of the pain.

Please note that ABC remains constant, but the numbers, represented above by 123, are always changing.

As it stands, the macro I have tried to put together is only able to find all of the instances of text starting with ABC. Is there an "If" I could add to the code that could find the instance of ABC that ends with a number?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Please post the code you have already tried, along with a representative sample of your document's text.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this search term to find `ABC` followed by 3 digits:

```
   ABC^#^#^#
```

Or, if you don't know how many digits there will be, you can use this wildcard search which will find `ABC` followed by 1-10 digits:

```
  With Selection.Find
    .MatchWildcards
    .Text = "ABC[0-9]{1,10}"
    .Execute
  End With
```